# C# CultureInfo.GetCultures returns a (nearly) empty list

Tags: .net, windows, cultureinfo

Windows 8.1 Pro, Visual Studio 2013, .NET Framework 4.5.2

Here is the code:

```
var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
Console.WriteLine("Culture count: " + cultures.Length);
```

Here is the output:

```
Culture count: 2
```

The two cultures are zh-CHS and zh-CHT which are added in the `CultureData.GetCultures` method. The other cultures are supposed to be returned by `CultureData.nativeEnumCultureNames` but it appears that this is returning an empty array.

This behavior appears to be limited to a single workstation. I've tried the same code on other computers and am getting normal results. How would I go about fixing this? I've attempted re-installing the .NET framework with no success.

**Edit 1:** This only affects .NET 4/4.5. If my project targets .NET 3.5, it works, returning 311 cultures.

Comment: The _note_ on MSDN mentions also the _"zh-CHS and zh-CHT cultures"_ explicitly, interesting. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures(v=vs.110).aspx Obviously on chinese computers no other cultures are allowed ;)

Comment: Did someone remove or uninstall something on that particular workstation? This behavior is not usual. Maybe re-install the machine in question?

Comment: No, this is a brand new installation. Got the laptop from Razer a week ago and I've been using it since. Came with Windows 8.1 standard, upgraded to Pro via a license code. Installed VS2013, etc. This is the first time that I'm having an issue. Ideally, I'd prefer not having to restore to factory defaults or even worse, apply a custom image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\ExtendedLocale is present. If it is missing, there is a [known issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ea0f2d35-958b-4621-9a0b-84fb9a443800/import-data-tier-application-collation-1033-is-not-supported?forum=ssdt) that can be worked around by adding this key.

Comment: Amazing. Worked just like that.